# Alert when a process exits

Tags: process, wget, curl, download

I often download files using `wget` and `cURL`.

Is there anyway I can make my Linux box give a visual alert when either of those processes exit (*i.e: the download completes*)

PS : I am using Ubuntu *oneiric ocelot* x86 and I switch between Unity and Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like `zenity` or `xmessage`. For example:

```
wgetmsg() {
    wget "$@" && zenity --info --text='Wget returned success.' || zenity --error --text='Wget returned failure.'
}

wgetmsg -O filename http://www.example.com
```